# How to extract table column and rows using beatifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Beautifulsoup noob here. Just for practice, I'm trying to extract the package and version column of [this page](https://launchpad.net/~openshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) here. I tried to get the table content using: `table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'listing sortable'})` but I'm not really getting any worthy data.. I'm very lost.

Here's the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://launchpad.net/~openshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.find_all(id='packages_list')[0].tbody

for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    package = tr.find_all('td')[0].contents[2].strip()
    version = tr.find_all('td')[1].contents[0].strip()
    print('{0} - {1}'.format(package, version))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table = soup.find("table", id="packages_list")
row_data = []
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    row_data.append(cols)
```

I'm not sure what results you're getting right now, but try this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `tr` tag and extract package and version :

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'listing sortable'})
package = '' ; version = ''
for i in table.select('tr'):
    data = i.select('td')
    if data:
        package = data[0].text.strip()
        version = ' '.join(data[1].text.strip().split())
        print('{} : {} '.format(package,version))

#output
libopenshot : 0.1.4+0+588+107+201703310338+daily~ubuntu17.04.1 
libopenshot : 0.1.4+0+588+107+201703310338+daily~ubuntu15.04.1 
libopenshot : 0.1.4+0+588+107+201703310337+daily~ubuntu16.10.1 
libopenshot : 0.1.4+0+588+107+201703310337+daily~ubuntu16.04.1 
...
...
```